# Homebrewがインストール出来ません！

Tags: homebrew

Homebrewをインストールするため、ターミナルにて

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

を入力しましたが、その際に`PASSWARD`を入力するよう表示されますが、その状態で文字キーを叩いても何も文字が入力されず、リターンキーのみ反応する状態です。やむを得ずリターンキーを押しますが、３回押すとそこで終了となってしまい、インストール出来ず困っております。
解決方法を何卒ご回答頂けませんでしょうか？

[image: 文字キーを叩いても反応しない状態のスクリーンショット]

Comment: 端末で`id`と入力してみてください。その中に`80(admin)`とありますか？なければ`sudo`が使えないと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
一応「80(admin)」を見つけることが出来ました！
https://gyazo.com/87220ac64ce3dcad2d809da2978d3e2b

Comment: であれば、すでに回答が出ているように、ご自身のパスワードを入力するだけですね、パスワードは表示されません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決致しました！

Answer (score 1):

表示されませんが入力されています。パスワードを入力して最後にリターンキーを押してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決致しました！

Comment: @福田友亮 本回答で解決した場合は回答の承認をよろしくおねがいいたします。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers